# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, ssl

I would like to surpass SSL verification when I send post request with the python requests module, but it gave me an error even when I added parameter `verify=False`:

My request:

```
response = session.request(rest_body["method"], url, data=data,
                                            headers=headers, proxies=PROXIES,
                                            cookies=req_cookies, verify=False)
```

Error (new lines added):

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token
  (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
  at 0x7f174234e5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
  Connection refused',))
```

What does this error mean, and how can I avoid it?